# ATOM text editor text colour change due to hash

Tags: html, css, atom-editor

In my HTML document I am trying to use HTML emojis in a span as follows:
[image]

Now, you can see that the emoji &#128200 makes for some reason the lines ahead of it orange. When I remove the hash it looks normal as the following: 
[image]

How can I normalize the text editor colour with still using the hash in the emoji, because at the moment all lines ahead are all orange.

Comment: A hashtag is a means of indicating that a term, in plain text, should be hyperlinked as a search term (on social media networks). It gets the name because it it uses a hash character to prefix it. Most things that use a hash symbol (including the hash symbol itself) are not hashtags.

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Character references should be terminated by a semicolon. This is probably what is confusing your syntax highlighter. Write valid HTML. Use [a validator](https://validator.nu/). (Voting to close as the problem is caused by a typo)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need too put semicolon at end of emoji